# reset jquery if 2 of 2 functions not executed within 5 seconds?

Tags: jquery

i am trying to add a timeout or reset to this piece of jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var $msgNav = $('.nav4');
$msgNav.on('click', handler);

function handler() {
    $('.drop_down_column3').toggle();

    handler = function () { //overwrite handler
        window.location.href = "messages.php"; //
    }

    $msgNav.off('click').on('click', handler);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

basically what is happening here is i am essentially making a navigation menu. if the user clicks on the div 'nav4' the first time then a dropbox/drop_down_column3 displays. Then if the user clicks 'nav4' the second time they are taken to a url link.

What i want to do now is add a time out function or a reset function to this so that if the user does not carry out the second click within 5 seconds then the jquery starts over or resets itself as if the first click hasn't happened yet.

can someone please show me how i might do this?

Comment: setTimeout and clearTimeout are your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
var $msgNav = $('.nav4'), $dropDown = $('.drop_down_column3');

$msgNav.one('click', handler); //Register the handler just once

function handler() {
    $dropDown.toggle();

    $msgNav.one('click', function () {  //Set up second click event
        window.location.href = "messages.php"; 
    });

    window.setTimeout(function(){ //Wait for 5 seconds 
        $dropDown.toggle();// Add this if you want to toggle the div again
        $msgNav.off('click').one('click', handler); //turnoff the handler and reset to old
    }, 5000)
    return false;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9VKj2/)**

Comment: @user3080996 Seems like you used my answer from your previous question as well related to this.. :)

Comment: yes i did, but you removed it briefly so i couldnt comment :/ - do you know if there is a way of adding a reset in the event of an off click nav4 or when user goes off focus of nav4?

Comment: @user3080996 I had added it back... :) To answer your question `focus` is for input element i don't think it will work on a div (assuming nav4 is a div but what you can do it to listen on mouseleave handler for nav4 i am not sure if that is what you need). How would you focus it anyways?

Comment: @user3080996 If you think i had an answer to your previous question (which you used for this question) you could accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this... I added excessive comments to explain.

If the second click doesn't always reload the page you could set a boolean state variable that gets set to true when they do the second click and reset on the first click. and is used to break out of the timeout function.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var $msgNav = $('.nav4');
  var timeoutHandle;
$msgNav.on('click', handler);

function handler() {
    var self=$(this);
    $('.drop_down_column3').toggle();
    //clear the timeout handle if it exists.
    // On show this gets ready for the next one if there is overlap
    // on hide it just gets rid of the timer
    if(timeoutHandle) clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    //if the menu is visible start the timer
    if($('.drop_down_column3').is(':visible'){
        timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function(){
            //re-toggle after the time period
            // no need to check for second click
            // because the second click leave the page anyways
            self.trigger('click');
        },5000);
    }
    handler = function () { //overwrite handler
        window.location.href = "messages.php"; //
    }

    $msgNav.off('click').on('click', handler);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You said it ... you need a timeout mechanism, basicaly, you can start a timeout like this

```
var timeoutId = window.setTimeout(handler, milis);
```

and after you do that, it can be canceled with:

```
window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```

Within your context you can try this:

```
var $msgNav = $('.nav4');
$msgNav.on('click', timedHandler);


var timeoutId;

function timedHandler(event) {
  if(timeoutId) {
    clickHandler();  
  } else { 
    waitingHandler();   
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(revertFirstClick, 5000);
  }
}

function clickHandler(){
  $msgNav.text('Clicked two times in 5 seconds!');

  $msgNav.off('click', timedHandler);
  cancelTimer();
}

function waitingHandler(){
  $msgNav.text('Quick! click me again before is too late!');
}

function revertFirstClick(){
  $msgNav.text('Click me!');

  cancelTimer();
}

function cancelTimer(){
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  timeoutId = null ;
}
```

See it in action here : http://jsbin.com/EtedIgiS/5/edit